# Iterate over files and extract a regex from the filename

Tags: bash

I have the following files:

```
ds-1000000000000000279-1176x2184.dat
tex-1000000000000000209-2048x4096.dat
tex-1000000000000000234-1920x1280.dat
tex-1000000000000000248-688x218.dat
tex-1000000000000000278-1176x2184.dat
```

and need to extract the resolution from the file names and execute the following command for each file (by example with the first file):

```
convert -size 1176x2184 -depth 32 gray:ds-1000000000000000054-1176x2184.dat ds-1000000000000000054-1176x2184.png
```

I was able to do this

```
for f in *.dat; do echo "$f"; done
```

but can't figure out how to extract the resolution.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to manipulate the strings:

```bash
for f in *.dat; do
  n="${f%.dat}"  # remove extension '.dat'
  r="${n##*-}"   # extract resolution
  convert -size "$r" -depth 32 "gray:$f" "$n.png"
done
```

With the file names given, this executes:

```
convert -size 1176x2184 -depth 32 gray:ds-1000000000000000279-1176x2184.dat ds-1000000000000000279-1176x2184.png
convert -size 2048x4096 -depth 32 gray:tex-1000000000000000209-2048x4096.dat tex-1000000000000000209-2048x4096.png
convert -size 1920x1280 -depth 32 gray:tex-1000000000000000234-1920x1280.dat tex-1000000000000000234-1920x1280.png
convert -size 688x218 -depth 32 gray:tex-1000000000000000248-688x218.dat tex-1000000000000000248-688x218.png
convert -size 1176x2184 -depth 32 gray:tex-1000000000000000278-1176x2184.dat tex-1000000000000000278-1176x2184.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cut`:

```
$ echo tex-1000000000000000278-1176x2184.dat | cut -d '.' -f 1 | cut -d '-' -f 3
1176x2184
```

The first `cut` selects the part before the dot, the second `cut` selects the third "dash separated" field.

Comment: Maybe simpler to get rid of the `echo` and do a `cut ... <<< ....` instead.

Comment: @user1934428 the `echo` was just to demonstrate the use of `| cut` with a complete command. Thank you for `<<<`, I didn't know about that.